# S3 bucket creation with aws-sdk-go on local stack ends up with location :/none

Tags: go, amazon-s3, localstack, aws-sdk-go

I have been trying to learn CRUD operations on S3 buckets using golang and localstack

using the below code

```
import (
    "fmt"
    "io/ioutil"
    "os"
    "strings"

    "github.com/aws/aws-sdk-go/aws"
    "github.com/aws/aws-sdk-go/aws/awserr"
    "github.com/aws/aws-sdk-go/aws/session"
    "github.com/aws/aws-sdk-go/service/s3"
)

var (
    s3session *s3.S3
)

const (
    REGION             = "us-east-1"
    Bucket_Name string = "sahil1234"
)

func init() {
    s3session = s3.New(session.Must(session.NewSession(&aws.Config{
        Region:   aws.String("us-east-1"),
        Endpoint: aws.String("http://localhost:4566/"),
    })))
}

func listBuckets() (resp *s3.ListBucketsOutput) {
    resp, err := s3session.ListBuckets(&s3.ListBucketsInput{})
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    return resp
}

func createBucket() (resp *s3.CreateBucketOutput) {
    resp, err := s3session.CreateBucket(&s3.CreateBucketInput{
        // ACL: aws.String(s3.BucketCannedACLPrivate),
        // ACL: aws.String(s3.BucketCannedACLPublicRead),
        Bucket: aws.String(Bucket_Name),
        CreateBucketConfiguration: &s3.CreateBucketConfiguration{
            LocationConstraint: aws.String(REGION),
        },
    })
    if err != nil {
        if aerr, ok := err.(awserr.Error); ok {
            switch aerr.Code() {
            case s3.ErrCodeBucketAlreadyExists:
                fmt.Println("Bucket name already in use!")
                panic(err)
            case s3.ErrCodeBucketAlreadyOwnedByYou:
                fmt.Println("Bucket exists and is owned by you!")
            default:
                panic(err)
            }
        }
    }

    return resp
}

func uploadObject(filename string) (resp *s3.PutObjectOutput) {
    f, err := os.Open(filename)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }

    fmt.Println("Uploading:", filename)
    resp, err = s3session.PutObject(&s3.PutObjectInput{
        Body:   f,
        Bucket: aws.String(Bucket_Name),
        Key:    aws.String(strings.Split(filename, "/")[1]),
        ACL:    aws.String(s3.BucketCannedACLPublicRead),
    })

    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }

    return resp
}

func listObjects() (resp *s3.ListObjectsV2Output) {
    resp, err := s3session.ListObjectsV2(&s3.ListObjectsV2Input{
        Bucket: aws.String(Bucket_Name),
    })

    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }

    return resp
}

func getObject(filename string) {
    fmt.Println("Downloading: ", filename)

    resp, err := s3session.GetObject(&s3.GetObjectInput{
        Bucket: aws.String(Bucket_Name),
        Key:    aws.String(filename),
    })

    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }

    body, err := ioutil.ReadAll(resp.Body)
    err = ioutil.WriteFile(filename, body, 0644)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
}

func deleteObject(filename string) (resp *s3.DeleteObjectOutput) {
    fmt.Println("Deleting: ", filename)
    resp, err := s3session.DeleteObject(&s3.DeleteObjectInput{
        Bucket: aws.String(Bucket_Name),
        Key:    aws.String(filename),
    })

    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }

    return resp
}

func main() {
    
    fmt.Println(listBuckets())
    fmt.Println(createBucket())
    fmt.Println(listBuckets())
}
```

even tho the creatBucket returns succesfully, it does not create an actual bucket,
it just returns

```
{
  Location: "/None"
}
```

The bucket also does not show up when i do `aws --endpoint-url=http://localhost:4566 s3 ls`

Any help would be much appreciated!

**output**:

```
{
  Buckets: [{
      CreationDate: 2021-09-29 07:25:21 +0000 UTC,
      Name: "my-bucket1212"
    }],
  Owner: {
    DisplayName: "webfile",
    ID: "bcaf1ffd86f41161ca5fb16fd081034f"
  }
}
{
  Location: "/None"
}
{
  Buckets: [{
      CreationDate: 2021-09-29 07:25:21 +0000 UTC,
      Name: "my-bucket1212"
    }],
  Owner: {
    DisplayName: "webfile",
    ID: "bcaf1ffd86f41161ca5fb16fd081034f"
  }
}
```

**PS**: *mybucket1212 is a bucket i created using aws-cli*

Answer (score 4, accepted):

the easiest option now is to set `S3ForcePathStyle` in your config:

```
S3ForcePathStyle: aws.Bool(true),
```

This is the way `aws-cli` is doing it.

but this options is being [deprecated by AWS](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/amazon-s3-path-deprecation-plan-the-rest-of-the-story/) even though without a set date.

I'll try and find a way to make it work without this option and update this answer.